# how to change the UMAP use in the dimplot and feature plot

Tags: seurat, single-cell

I would like to know how to change the UMAP used in `Dimplot` and `FeaturePlot` from Seurat: how we can get the x-axis and the y-axis like UMAP-1 and UMAP-2 if I want to use UMAP-4 and UMAP-5. How to modify the code? It is easy to change the PC by using `DimPlot(object = pbmc_small, dims = c(4, 5), reduction = "PCA")` but if I changed to `reduction = "UMAP"`, I got the error

```
"Error in Embeddings(object = object[[reduction]])[cells, dims] : subscript out of bounds Calls: DimPlot Execution halted".
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: that is because UMAP-4 and UMAP-5 are not present in your object...head(object[['umap']]@cell.embeddings), or str(object[['umap']]@cell.embeddings)

Comment: Yes, the UMAP-4 and UMAP-5 are not present in my project. So what should I do now?

Comment: What is the rationale for using UMAP-4 and UMAP-5? UMAP is different from PCA because you specify a dimension (usually) and it tries to put all information in those two dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(Seurat)
pbmc_small <- RunUMAP(pbmc_small, dims = 1:10, reduction = "pca", n.components = 5)

names(pbmc_small[["umap"]])
#> [1] "UMAP_1" "UMAP_2" "UMAP_3" "UMAP_4" "UMAP_5"

# plot
DimPlot(pbmc_small, reduction = "umap", dims = c(4, 5))
```

[image]

This should work with Seurat version 3.1.5

```r
packageVersion("Seurat")
#> [1] '3.1.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `n.components` / `max.dims` (depending on your seurat version) to 5 when you call `runUMAP` and you should have dim 4 and 5 available.

Comment: Hi Pallie, i have tried to use "SAN <- RunUMAP(SAN, dims = 1:10, max.dim = 5L, dims.keep = 5L)"  and there still are no UMAP-4 and UMAP-5.